# LINQ to SQL SubmitChangess() progress

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, progress, submitchanges

I'm using LINQ to SQLto import old DBF files into MSSQL.
I'm reading all rows and adding them to database using `ctx.MyTable.InsertOnSubmit(row)`

After reading phase is completed I have around 100 000 pending inserts.
`ctx.SubmitChanges()` naturally is taking a long time.

Is there any way to track progress of the `ctx.submitchanges()`?
Can `ctx.Log` somehow be used for this purpose?

**Update**: Is it possible to use `ctx.GetChangeSet().Inserts.Count` and track insert statements using the Log?

Dividing `ctx.SubmitChanges()` into smaller chunks is not working for me, because I need transaction, all or nothing.

**Update 2:**
I've found nice class ActionTextWriter using which I will try to count inserts.

http://damieng.com/blog/2008/07/30/linq-to-sql-log-to-debug-window-file-memory-or-multiple-writers

**Update 3:**

I've build first code prototype, it's not optimized. It seems to be working :)

```
ctx.Log = new ActionTextWriter(s => {
 counter += s.Split(' ').Count(w => w.ToUpper() == "INSERT");
 ReportProgress(counter);
});
```

Comment: Same question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648379/how-can-i-get-a-percentage-of-linq-to-sql-submitchanges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get progress informations by parsing log and using ActionTextWriter

http://damieng.com/blog/2008/07/30/linq-to-sql-log-to-debug-window-file-memory-or-multiple-writers

```
ctx.Log = new ActionTextWriter(s => {
    if (s.StartsWith("INSERT INTO"))
        insertsCount++;
});
```